# The command ng generate service says already exist

Tags: angular, angular-cli

On my Mac, I am trying to create a service but it not working.
I have been following [this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X5n353jld6o&list=PLYxzS__5yYQlqCmHqDyW3yo5V79C7eaTe&index=18) for learning Angular and has used exactly his code.

The error I have been getting is:

> Ankits-MBP:project ankit$ ng generate service user  already exists.con
>   The Schematic workflow failed. See above.

Comment: what is the angular cli version

Answer (score 0):

The error point out the service already exist in a clearly way, maybe you have launched twice the generation of the new service and this have triggered the error.

Are you sure you have specified well the path in which save your service? Maybe Angular have already created the service and you didn't find it.

Maybe you can try to specify a different path and see if the generation work correctly.

```
ng generate service custom-path/service-name
```

or shorter syntax

```
ng g s custom-path/service-name
```

(If you have created project via CLI, you shoul find the new service under `project-name/src/app/custom-path/service-name.service.ts` folder)